# Código sendo realizado apenas quando clica duas vezes?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Bom, precisei fazer com que ao clicar em um botão mostrasse as div's e se ao clicar em outro botão e a alguma div estiver aparecendo(display:block;) iria adquirir um display: none; foi o que fiz no código a baixo:

```js
function movel(){
 var divMovel = document.getElementById("divMovel");

 if(divMovel.style.display == "none" || divRoupa.style.display == "block" || divOutros.style.display == "block" || divCozinha.style.display == "block"){
  divMovel.style.display = "block";
  divRoupa.style.display = "none";
  divOutros.style.display = "none";
  divCozinha.style.display = "none";
 }

 else{
  divMovel.style.display = "none";
 }
};

function roupa(){
 var divRoupa = document.getElementById("divRoupa");
 
 if(divRoupa.style.display == "none" || divMovel.style.display == "block" || divOutros.style.display == "block" || divCozinha.style.display == "block" ){
  divMovel.style.display = "none";
  divOutros.style.display = "none";
  divCozinha.style.display = "none";
  divRoupa.style.display = "block";
 }
 else{
  divRoupa.style.display = "none";
 }
};

function outros(){
 var divOutros = document.getElementById("divOutros");
 
 if(divOutros.style.display == "none" || divRoupa.style.display == "block" || divMovel.style.display == "block" || divCozinha.style.display == "block" ){
  divRoupa.style.display = "none";
  divMovel.style.display = "none";
  divCozinha.style.display = "none";
  divOutros.style.display = "block";
 }
 else{
  divOutros.style.display = "none";
 }
};

function cozinha(){
 var divCozinha = document.getElementById("divCozinha");
 
 if(divCozinha.style.display == "none" || divRoupa.style.display == "block" || divMovel.style.display == "block" || divOutros.style.display == "block"){
  divRoupa.style.display = "none";
  divMovel.style.display = "none";
  divOutros.style.display = "none";
  divCozinha.style.display = "block";
 }
 else{
  divCozinha.style.display = "none";
 }
};
```

```css
.itens{
 position: relative;
 margin: auto;
 width: 80%;
 height: 600px;
 background-color: white;
}
.moveis{
 position: relative;
 margin: auto;
 width: 80%;
 height: 600px;
 background-color: green;
 display: none;
}
.roupa{
 position: relative;
 margin: auto;
 width: 80%;
 height: 600px;
 background-color: blue;
 display: none;

}
.outros{
 position: relative;
 margin: auto;
 width: 80%;
 height: 600px;
 background-color: red;
 display: none;

}
.cozinha{
 position: relative;
 margin: auto;
 width: 80%;
 height: 600px;
 background-color: black;
 display: none;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="boxGeral">
  <aside class="classes">
   <ul>
        <!--Os botões -->
    <li><button id="linkMovel" onclick="movel()">Móveis</button></li>
    <li><button id="linkRoupa" onclick="roupa()">Roupas</button></li>
    <li><button id="linkOutros" onclick="outros()">Outros</button></li>
    <li><button id="linkCozinha" onclick="cozinha()">Itens de Cozinha</button></li>
   </ul>
  </aside>
    <!--As div que irão aparecer -->
  <article class="itens">
   <div class="moveis" id="divMovel">
    asdasdasd
   </div>
   <div class="roupa" id="divRoupa">
    333333
   </div>
   <div class="outros" id="divOutros">
    333333
   </div>
   <div class="cozinha" id="divCozinha">
    333333
   </div>
  </article>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Porém por algum motivo o script só é executado quando se clica duas vezes sobre o botão, quero saber a solução que fará com que seja aparecido assim quando clicar.
OBS: Utilizando somente HTML, CSS e JS(Sem jQuery).Se possível mostrar também uma solução com jQuery utilizando algum efeito como o toggle. Agradecido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema que está a acorrer é que apesar de os elementos começarem escondidos a propriedade `display.style` de cada um deles começa vazia, depois passa a `none` e só então mostra.

Esse é o motivo de ter de dar dois cliques para mostrar.

No entanto, todo o código é um pouco repetido. Uma melhor solução para o problema seria:

```js
var divs = [
  document.getElementById("divMovel"),
  document.getElementById("divRoupa"),
  document.getElementById("divOutros"),
  document.getElementById("divCozinha")
]; //criar um array com todos os divs a mostrar

divs.forEach(x => x.style.display = "none"); //iniciar todos escondidos

//funcao agora para todos os botoes, que recebe a posicao do div a controlar
function ativar(posicao){      
  if (divs[posicao].style.display == "none"){ 
    divs.forEach(x => x.style.display = "none"); //esconde todos os outros
    divs[posicao].style.display = "block"; //mostra este
  }
  else {
    divs[posicao].style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.itens{
 position: relative;
 margin: auto;
 width: 80%;
 height: 600px;
 background-color: white;
}
.moveis{
 position: relative;
 margin: auto;
 width: 80%;
 height: 600px;
 background-color: green;
 display: none;
}
.roupa{
 position: relative;
 margin: auto;
 width: 80%;
 height: 600px;
 background-color: blue;
 display: none;

}
.outros{
 position: relative;
 margin: auto;
 width: 80%;
 height: 600px;
 background-color: red;
 display: none;

}
.cozinha{
 position: relative;
 margin: auto;
 width: 80%;
 height: 600px;
 background-color: black;
 display: none;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="boxGeral">
  <aside class="classes">
                        <!--Os botões -->
   <ul>       
    <li><button id="linkMovel" onclick="ativar(0)">Móveis</button></li>
    <li><button id="linkRoupa" onclick="ativar(1)">Roupas</button></li>
    <li><button id="linkOutros" onclick="ativar(2)">Outros</button></li>
    <li><button id="linkCozinha" onclick="ativar(3)">Itens de Cozinha</button></li>
   </ul>
  </aside>

                <!--As div que irão aparecer -->
  <article class="itens">
   <div class="moveis" id="divMovel">
    asdasdasd
   </div>
   <div class="roupa" id="divRoupa">
    333333
   </div>
   <div class="outros" id="divOutros">
    333333
   </div>
   <div class="cozinha" id="divCozinha">
    333333
   </div>
  </article>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

O que implicou mudar também a chamada a função no html para `onclick="ativar(0)"` para o primeiro `li`, e assim sucessivamente para os restantes.

**JQuery**

Para jquery não seriam necessário os atributos `onclick` nos `li`, assim como não seria necessário um *array* para controlar os vários elementos.

```
$(function(){
    $(".classes li").click(function(){
      //construir a posição clicada com base no li
      var indice = $(this).index() + 1; 
      //ir buscar o elemento correspondente com base no seletor nth-child
      var elemento = $(".itens > div:nth-child(" + indice + ")"); 

      if (elemento.is(":visible") === true) { //ver se esta visível
        elemento.hide(); //esconder o elemento corrente se estava visível
      }
      else {
        $(".itens > div").hide(); //esconder todos
        elemento.show(); //mostrar o que interessa
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: Muito bom, porém quando eu tirava os "else" das minhas funções parava de funcionar o script, seria por qual motivo ?

Comment: Sem o else o elemento nunca ia a `display.none`, logo também depois não conseguia voltar a `display.block` pela lógica dos `ifs`

Comment: Por algum motivo eu copiei o seu código tanto do jQuery quanto o outro e não funcionou mas consegui resolver apenas adicionando um .style.display = "none", depois da declaração de cada variável de cada função fazendo com que eles já iniciem como none, além de poder tirar o else.

Comment: O de JQuery para funcionar tem de estar dentro de `$(function(){ });`, que é o que garante que o código apenas é interpretado depois de o html estar construído. Quanto ao de Js normal é estranho porque o snippet funciona na perfeição.